# Computing a .setOnMouseMoved() event in another thread

Tags: java, javafx

I have a Scene with an HBox as the Nodes parent, that only contains some ImageViews;

I added a .setOnMouseMoved() event to  this HBox that calculates each ImageView distance from the cursor, and scales their dimensions based on how far they are from it:

I'd like to move this computation to another thread to "lighten" the JavaFX Application Thread, and doing a Platform.runLater() when the scale values are ready, but still don't know how to proceed:

My first attempt was simply putting everything in a thread, and calling a Platform.runLater() at the end, but it doesn't seem to work;

Can someone give me a hint? Thanks!

Comment: Show me some codeeeh! :) chop chop

Comment: Read: [Concurrency in JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm).  Implement your code based upon it.  Run some benchmarks on the code that you are trying to multi-thread.  Ensure that it is worthwhile multi-threading it.  If you still have issues, then post an [mcve].

Comment: Maybe you could start an infinite `Task<Double>`, add a listener to the `valueProperty`. This task would have a boolean property that the task would listen to, and, when modified by your `setOnMouseMoved`, would recalculate the scale, modify it's `valueProperty` (which will trigger the event in the main thread, that will modify the image scale). I don't know if it's worth doing multithreaded computation for this though...

Comment: I know it's not worth it, I want to do it because I'm still learning JavaFX concurrency, and this "experience" may help me later...

Comment: This sounds like a computation that shouldn't be too complex. Probably the overhead of synchronizing the results outweighs the time saved by moving those computations to a different thread...